# How do I have the mouse move to a pixel position | Autoit

Tags: autoit

So, do you know how I could have the mouse go to the position of a pixel (that moves) as soon as it sees it ?

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm was already tried, what I would need is a way to have the cooridinates replaced with the location where the pixel were found.

Comment: [PixelSearch](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm)

Comment: As Stephan said, use `PixelSearch`, simply make a `while` loop with `PixelSearch` and `MouseMove` to position if found, if you want a code example, please add some code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
$coord = PixelSearch( 760, 50, 970, 95, 0x16AB39 )
MouseClick('left',$coord[0],$coord[1])
```